# On axios.get() request, response ONLY return the image header NOT image data?

Tags: axios, playwright

I`m writing tests in playwright where I check if all the images on my web page are valid.

I`m using Axios get request to get the image URL/path and because some of the images are quite big, I was thinking, one way to expedite tests, would be to only check the image header (image.size i.e.) and not even return the image data from Axios response, is this in any way possible with Axios or do I have to use another library for that?

```
 await axios.all(allImagesURLs.map(imageURL => axios.get(imageURL))).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
        for (const response of responses) {
           expect.soft(response.status).toBe(200)
       }

    })).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet you have used ?

Answer (score 1):

I used axios.head() request, which only returns the response header and not the image data.